# Android - create a background service to pull update from server

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

My idea is simple. I have an e-book app with multiple chapters. From time to time, new chapters will be uploaded to server. I want to have a background service in the user's mobile phone to pull the latest chapters from server and download it if any, maybe in a weekly or daily basis

After googling, I have tried to use AlarmManager + IntentService + BroadcastReceiver, but it does not work when the app is killed by the user. I think this is a common action from user to save the memory and kill all the applications after used

Is there any way to split the service and application into different processes, so that the background service is not easily killed by the user, at least not visible when e.g. for my phone press left button will view all running applications, unless he/she goes to setting and view it.

Thank you!

Comment: ok, after spending more than 4 hours of debugging, it appears to be the device issue. Some china brand smartphone like xiaomi will auto stop alarm manager and background service as soon as the app is killed, unless user explicitly grants the "autostart" permission to the app. Although some well-known apps like whatsapp and line will be automatically added to the list, but it still looks weird for me to have such restriction

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions. The better way is to use `Sockets`. Then it's server responsibility to send updates for your android device.

another way is as you said using services. There are some points you have to consider to keep you service alive. **First**: don't use a bound service. **Second**: you have to restart your service when whole app is closing(it's not even in background).you can do it in your service in you `onTaskRemoved` method. It will help you:

```
    @Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(this, yourService.class);
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

}
```

Tell me if it helped you. Don't hesitate to ask any other question :)

Comment: sorry.that was a typo mistake.I meant "Bound service". you can see the definitions on developer.android.com. When you use bound service it only lives till the component that it's bind to exist.